# AutoMake - Source file used in more than one binary

Tags: automake

Attention AutoMake experts... ;)
What is the "proper" way of using certain source files in multiple binaries?
I have a client and a server, and there are some "shared" source files (parse.c/parse.h and message.c/message.h). And of course I have to binaries listed (`bin_PROGRAMS = client server`). So where in the Makefile.am should parse.c/h and message.c/h be? Listed twice, once in the client's sources and once in the server's sources?

Comment: There are several "proper" ways to do it.  As you suggest, listing each file in `client_SOURCES` and in `server_SOURCES` is fine.  Or us a convenience library.  Or install a stand-alone library.  Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought there might be some other, better, way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it, was put the .h files in question in `EXTRA_DIST` and the .c files in both `server_SOURCES` and `client_SOURCES`. Not sure if that is the best way to do it, but it works.